# Video compression before uploading on Firestore

Tags: android, video, camera, compression, google-cloud-firestore

I want to let my users upload videos with a length of ~20-30 seconds. My problem right now is that these recorded videos have an average size of 10Mb, which is imo a bit to huge.

I'm using the [CameraView](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) library for recording, with the `h264 codec` and `max480p` setting (It's using the Camera1 library).

I already tried to compress the video with [SiliCompressor](https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor), which gave me a really bad quality and I read about FFmpeg but I don't want to buy a 400$ license.

Which options do I have ? Are 10mb not too much ?
(I want to upload these videos to Google Firestore)

Answer (score 0):

10mb for 20 seconds is 4mbps. That is a little high for 480p, but it’s not crazy high. And if it has audio as well, I would say that size is spot on. You can reduce the bitrate when you encode, but it will result in a quality loss. Also anyone trying to charge you $400 for [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) is scaming you.

Comment: That's what I founded [here](https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor/issues/20). Isn't that for all ffmpeg libraries ? From my understanding I have to open my code to use it free (what I don't want in my position) or I have to pay the license ? Or can I use it free ?

Comment: ffmpeg4android is not the same thing as ffmepg.